# rbind not giving expected output in r

Tags: r

I created an empty data frame with column names and was trying to insert rows containing a string and a number. This is my code, however I do not get the expected output.

```
df <- data.frame(col1=character(), col2=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
for(i in 1:10)
{
    entry = c("hello",i)
    df = rbind(df,entry)
}
```

EDIT : The rbind line initially looked like this , testdf = rbind(df,entry). Thanks Pascal for pointing out, editing this since it was a typo.

EDIT-TWO : I tried doing based on Gregor's suggestion to create the columns first and them bind them together. But how do I ensure that the column names remain as firstcol and secondcol,and don't change to col1 and col2?

```
df <- data.frame(col1=character(), col2=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
firstcol = NULL
secondcol = NULL

for(i in 1:10)
{
    col1 = c(col1,"hello")
    col2 = c(col2,i)
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting `testdf` at each iteration. And you append nothing to `df`. And `entry` is not what you think it is.

Comment: and you won't have a `numeric` column because when you do `entry=c("hello",i)`, `i` is automatically converted to `character`

Comment: With a `for` loop, you should always try to debug by running each line, and seeing what's what. So initialize `df`, then in you console put `i = 1`, then run `entry = c("hello", i)`, then type `entry` in your console. Is it what you want? And so on.

Comment: The better way to build a data frame is to build the columns individually, and then after your loop `cbind()` them together. And better than building the columns with `c()`, you should initialize them to their final length, and then just fill in as you go. This will be **much** more efficient.

Comment: @Pascal, sorry the testdf part was a typo. thanks for pointing out, have edited it. But even with this, it doesn't work because like you said, the fault lies in the 'entry' part. How do I rectify this in a way that I can make a row and then rbind it to the data frame?

Comment: I guess you'll have to make a "row-data.frame" because there is no way to make a `vector` that is half `character` and `half` numeric... why exactly do you need to `rbind` a row ? because this is clearly not the best way to create a `data.frame`...

Comment: I agree with CathG and Gregor. Could give us the reason you want to iterate through rows?

Comment: @Pascal, I tried doing it based on the suggestion to individually create row values and then bind together, but how do I ensure that I don't lose the original column names. Please see EDIT-TWO

Comment: @IAMTubby, see my answer and the suggestions at the end, you can create your columns and then create your data.frame. This way, the column names will be exactly as you want

Comment: Usually, a `data.frame` is constructed like that: `DF <- data.frame(firstcol = "hello", secondcol = 1:10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***this is not an answer for a way to efficiently build a `data.frame`***, this is just to "correct" your loop in a way you'll get what you want:

you can do:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=character(), col2=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
for(i in 1:10)
{
    entry = data.frame(col1="hello",col2=i,stringsAsFactors=F)
    df = rbind(df,entry)
}
```

and you'll get:

```
head(df)
#    col1 col2
#1  hello    1
#2  hello    2
#3  hello    3
#4  hello    4
#5  hello    5
#6  hello    6
```

***However***, depending on what you want to do, you can, as @Gregor suggested:

- create `col1` and `col2` separatly and then either `cbind` them or create your `data.frame` with `df <- data.frame(col1=col1, col2=col2, stringsAsFactors=F)`
- create your `data.frame` with desired dimensions with `df <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=10, ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, paste0("col", 1:2))),stringsAsFactors=F)` and fill it the way you want afterwards (e.g. in a loop).

Comment: thanks for the reply. As I said in an earlier comment, I tried doing using the first point you menion above, ie, create col1 and col2 separatly and then either cbind them. But how do I not lose column names. Please see EDIT-TWO

Comment: @IAMTubby, the best way IMO will be, after you created you 2 columns, to create your `df` with the line of code I put at the end of my first point: `df <- data.frame(col1=col1, col2=col2, stringsAsFactors=F)` (of course, no need to create your data.frame before creating your columns)