# Problem with rbind object to data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, oop

I created a Table:

```
RpgCharDF <- data.frame(Name = character(),
                        Level = integer(),
                        ClassChar = character(),
                        Race = character(),
                        HP = integer(),
                        Attack = integer(),
                        Resist = integer())
```

Wrote a contructor function:

```
RPGcharacter <- function(name, level, rpgClass, race, HP, attack, resist){
    value <- list(name= name, level = level, rpgClass = rpgClass, HP = HP, attack = attack, resist = resist)
    attr(value, "class") <- "RPGcharacter"
    value
}
```

Created two object by funtion:

```
Artur <- RPGcharacter("Artur", 22, "Warlock", "Dwarf", 130, 12, 3)
Dawid <- RPGcharacter("Dawid", 1, "Homeless", "Gnome", 20, 2, 1)
```

And until now, everything works perfectly. I got in enviroment a proper DF and two object as list with 6 values.

Now I tried add objects to DF:

```
RpgCharDF <- rbind(RpgCharDF, Dawid)
RpgCharDF <- rbind(RpgCharDF, Artur)
```

And I got an error:

```
Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "Artur") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "Warlock") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

It's warning so object has been added to DF, but it looks that:

```
    NAME  Level RPGClass   HP  ATTACK  RESIST
1   Dawid   1   Homeless    20    2      1
2   NA      22  NA         130   12      3
```

There are NA values in DF.

Where have I done a mistake? What's wrong with that code? I need to notice that both elements Artur and Dawid are created normally. Both have a filled Name etc. when I click in environment.

Comment: You can convert to `character` class and should be fine

Comment: Well written question. Keep it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `rbind` it converts the output to a `data.frame`. As you do not specify how strings should be handeld, they are converted to a factor and thus, when you try to add the second row, it gives an NA for the character columns name and attack.

You can either use:

```
RpgCharDF <- rbind(RpgCharDF, Dawid, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
RpgCharDF <- rbind(RpgCharDF, Artur, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

or:

```
RpgCharDF <- do.call(rbind, list(RpgCharDF, Dawid, Artur))
```

Additional note:

Building a data.frame row by row is probably very slow in R, so rbindlist as recommended by @HarshalGajare is faster. See also the discussion here:
[rbind not giving expected output in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556857/rbind-not-giving-expected-output-in-r)
and here:
[R: Unable to rbind more than one observation to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756144/r-unable-to-rbind-more-than-one-observation-to-a-data-frame)

Comment: Thank U very much for explanations! Works fine :) Maybe U know why indexes (rownames) in DF is 2 and 21? Not 1 and 2?

Comment: Hmm... that is weird indeed... I don't know ad hoc why you get these rownames, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use rbindlist instead of rbind:

```
RpgCharDF <- data.frame(Name = character(),
                        Level = integer(),
                        rpgClass = character(),
                        Race = character(),
                        HP = integer(),
                        Attack = integer(),
                        Resist = integer())

RPGcharacter <- function(Name, Level, rpgClass, Race, HP, Attack, Resist){
  value <- list(Name= Name, Level = Level, rpgClass = rpgClass,Race=Race, HP = HP, Attack = Attack, Resist = Resist)
  attr(value, "class") <- "RPGcharacter"
  value
}

library(data.table)

Artur <- RPGcharacter("Artur", 22, "Warlock", "Dwarf", 130, 12, 3)
Dawid <- RPGcharacter("Dawid", 1, "Homeless", "Gnome", 20, 2, 1)

RpgCharDF <- rbindlist(list(RpgCharDF, Dawid, Artur), fill = T, use.names = T)
RpgCharDF
```

I think your column names are with different cases. that might be issue.